# Initial quantum state of a molecule in an ensemble with Boltzmann distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The dynamic of rotational states of an ensemble of molecules in temperature T is the purpose of my simulations. Thermal distribution of molecules is defined by Boltzmann distribution and spacing between the rotational states is small enough that for a temperature like 300K the states from J=0 to J=15 are occupied. A laser pulse interacts with the molecules and this brings them to a series of what is called as "Rotational revivals". Hence after time "t" the state of molecule is:

$$\big|\psi(t)\big\rangle = \sum_J a_J(t)\big|J\big\rangle$$
where "J" is the rotational quantum number and $|J\rangle$ is the orthogonal kets of rotation space.

I am trying to numerically simulate the process so I need the initial states and **My question is: What are the initial expansion coefficient, $a_J(t=0)$, for each J?**. I guess that should be $a_J(t=0)=\sqrt{P_J}$ where $P_J$ is the probability of finding the molecule in state J according to Boltzmann distribution. This also holds the normalization condition that $\sum_J |a_J(t=0)|^2=1.$

Comment: If you want to work with a thermal distribution, you have to consider a density matrix $\rho = \sum_J{|J\rangle P_J \langle J|}$, where $P_J$ is as you suggested. But for the time evolution you have to calculate what becomes of each contributing state $|J\rangle$ under your evolution operator since $\rho(t) = \sum_J{U(t)|J\rangle P_J \langle J|U^\dagger(t)} = \sum_J{|J(t)\rangle P_J \langle J(t)|}$. Note that the $|J(t)\rangle$-s are no longer eigenstates of $\rho(t)$ !